# Method Inheritance Through Prototypes

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following test code, I want `obj.my().showTxt()` to display "test1", but nothing is displayed, what error did I make?
Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
Primitive and String Objects
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Class1() {
        this.showTxt = function () { alert(this.name) }
    }

    Object.prototype.my = Class1;

    var obj = new Object();
    obj.name = "test1";

    obj.my().showTxt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I think"* - Seriously? Try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: `obj.my()` returns `undefined` since the function `Class1` does not return any value. Inside the function `this` will refer to `obj`. So you could do `obj.my(); obj.showTxt();`. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, the whole setup looks strange to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This bit is wrong: `Object.prototype.my = Class1`. It needs to be: `Object.prototype.my = new Class1()`. Everything else need not change. Javascript objects can only inherit from other objects, not constructors. Remember, javascript don't have classes!

Comment: Thanks! To slebetman:    but Object.prototype.my = new Class1() is wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that your function `Class1` was not returning an instance of itself.

Is this close to what you were trying to achieve?

```
function Class1() {
    this.show = function() {
        alert('test');
    }

    return this;
}

Object.prototype.my = Class1;

var obj = new Object();

obj.my().show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4ZgF/

The function Class1 returns undefined (as it has no return statement). Therefore Object.prototype.my is equal to undefined which does not have a function called showTxt(). By return this you have now returned the object which has that function on it.

Using your browser's debugger will help a lot to step through each line and see what is going on.

Comment: It works when I add return this!

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 
    function Class1() { 
        this.showTxt = function () { alert(this.name) }
        return this; 
    } 
 
    Object.prototype.my = Class1; 
 
    var obj = new Object(); 
    obj.name = "test1"; 
 
    obj.my().showTxt(); 
 
</script>

Comment: But I don't understand why I need add return this;

Comment: The function `Class1` returns `undefined` (as it has no return statement). Therefore `Object.prototype.my` is equal to `undefined` which does not have a function called `showTxt()`. By return `this` you have now returned the object which has that function on it.

Comment: @user828896: I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript Guide to get a better idea of the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of rearranging I think you can achieve what you want to do. Here's an example:

```
function Class1() {
    this.name = null;
}

Class1.prototype = {
    showTxt: function () { alert(this.name) }
};

var c = new Class1();
c.name = "test1";

c.showTxt();​
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UDPx6/)**

Though without really knowing what you're trying to accomplish, I'm not sure what else we can do here. Are you trying to extend every single `Object` with a `showTxt()` function?